# php session variables not working on server

Tags: php, session

i have a problem with my website on server,
I am new to php

my login page contains the following code:

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'marutinrutyakala.co.uk'); 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['name']= $adminname; 
    $_SESSION['login']=true; 
    $_SESSION['start']=time(); 
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=performance.php">';
```

now on  performance.php the code is

```
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
    { echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">'; }
```

Page code to execute here........

This code worked fine on local host but fails on server......

please help....

Comment: Do you have `session_set_cookie_params()` on subsequent pages?

Comment: Is it necessary to use session_set_cookie_params() at every page of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) of `session_set_cookie_params`:

The effect of this function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to call session_`set_cookie_params()` for every request and before `session_start()` is called.

So your performance.php should probably be:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'marutinrutyakala.co.uk'); 
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) 
{ echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">'; }
```

Check the domain name of the server. You are explicitly stating that your session cookie is only for the maruntinrutyakala.co.uk domain: is that the correct domain?

Try without the `session_set_cookie_params` line, does it work then?

Check your PHP [error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log): does an error appear there?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in top of the page

```
ob_start();
```

This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.